# Bash Awk command giving error in Hadoop Guide

Tags: bash, hadoop, awk

I am trying to replciate the example of Hadoop The definitive guide and don't where its going wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for year in /home/*
do
        echo -ne `basename $year .gz`"\t"
        gunzip -c $year | awk '{temp = substr($0, 88, 5) + 0; q = substr($0, 93, 1); if (temp !=9999 && q ~ /[01459] && temp > max) max = temp }
                          END {print max}'
done
```

The erro I am getting is

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {temp = substr($0, 88, 5) + 0; q = substr($0, 93, 1); if (temp !=9999 && q ~ /[01459] && temp > max) max = temp }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2:                         END {print max}
awk: cmd. line:2:                                        ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Also tried various changes but its not working.

Comment: missing `/` char on the reg ex, should be `/[01459]/ ...` Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shelter. You saved the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be

```
q ~ /[01459]/
```

You are missing the terminating slash.